# Как работают корни при x **1/n?

Tags: javascript

Только начал учить JS, и нашел задание на корни. Дело вроде не трудное, и не требует усилий.
Попробовал я формулу x ** (1/n) . Квадратный корень работает идеально, но вот проблема в кубической степени. **При 125 из под корня 3, получается не 5 , а 4,999999**. Почему оно так работает?
UPD : Заметил, что 27 из под корня 3, выдает правильный ответ, другие же увы

```js
function root(x,n){
    var result;
    result = x ** (1/n);
    return result;
}
alert(root(125,3));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="test.js"></script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего дело в двоичных числах и иррациональности дроби 1/3, которая не может быть представлена конечным числом бит. В итоге происходит округление показателя степени.

Многие дроби, даже будучи рациональными в десятичной системе, становятся иррациональными в двоичной. Из-за этого число 1/3 представляется как близкое к нему с погрешностью в каком-то далёком от запятой знаке (зависит от точности представления).

Дальше идёт процесс вычислений, в котором идёт одна или более операций. Каждая операция даст погрешность зависимую от погрешности операндов плюс накинет свою. Иногда погрешности гасят друг друга, а иногда складываются. Отсюда и получается, что иногда результат верный, а иногда немного не точный.

Comment: Другие работают без помех , такие как, 1/4 , 1/5 1/6 1/7

Comment: Сперва работает округление аргумента, которое может приводить к ошибкам. А затем идёт округление результата, которое иногда повышает ошибку, а иногда нет. Не знаю что чаще.

Comment: @JesuitOkkamoto если взять числа побольше, то погрешности всё равно проявляются, например (6.0**6)**(1/6)

Answer (score 3):

В JavaScript есть всего лишь один тип для представления чисел – Number, напоминающий double из Java. Это числа двойной точности (64 разряда) с плавающей точкой, соответствующие стандарту [IEEE 754](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008).

Суть концепции чисел с плавающей точкой заключается в разделении одного числа на два:

мантисса, или значимая часть, содержит цифры;
экспонента указывает, где в мантиссе необходимо расположить десятичную точку.
В самом старшем разряде числа хранится его знак, еще 11 битов отведено под экспоненту, оставшиеся занимает мантисса.

Проблемы такого формата широко известны – он плохо справляется с десятичными дробями. Особенно это важно при работе с денежными суммами. Так, язык JavaScript (и не только он) не может точно представить 0.1 и большую часть других дробей, которые в двоичной системе являются бесконечными.